# Uncaught Error: Error when checking : expected conv2d_input to have 4 dimension(s), but got array with shape [275,183,3]

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, tensorflow.js

I performed following operations on the images before training my keras model:

```
for img in os.listdir(path):    
    # convert to array
    img_array = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path,img) ,cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE) 
    # resize to normalize data size
    new_array = cv2.resize(img_array, (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE)) 
    # add this to our training_data list
    training_data.append([new_array, class_num]) 

#shuffle the data 
random.shuffle(training_data)

#empty lists (X for features, y for labels)
X = []
y = []

for features,label in tqdm(training_data):
    X.append(features)
    y.append(label)


X = np.array(X).reshape(-1, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 1)
```

I am then training the model. Here is the starting layer:

```
#start creating model 
model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(256, (3, 3), input_shape=X.shape[1:])
```

I am using the using the trained model to get some predictions( **I am training the  model in python and then I am loading the model into Tensorflow.js**)

Code snippet for prediction

```
let imageTensor = tf.fromPixels(image);
model.predict(imageTensor).print();
```

I am getting the following error:

> Uncaught Error: Error when checking : expected conv2d_input to have 4
>   dimension(s), but got array with shape [275,183,3]

Changing the above code to

```
let imageTensor = tf.fromPixels(image).resizeNearestNeighbor([50,50]).mean(2).toInt().expandDims(2);
model.predict(imageTensor).print();
```

gives following error:

> Uncaught Error: Error when checking : expected conv2d_input to have 4
>   dimension(s), but got array with shape [50,50,1]

lastly, when I do this

```
let imageTensor = tf.fromPixels(image).resizeNearestNeighbor([50,50]).toInt().expandDims();
 model.predict(imageTensor).print();
```

I get the following error:

> Error when checking : expected conv2d_input to have shape
>   [null,50,50,1] but got array with shape [1,50,50,3].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is related to a mismatch of the dimension of the input of the model and the dimension of the image passed in as parameter to the predict method.

One might consider reshaping the image the following way:

```
imageTensor.reshape([-1, 50, 50, 3])
```

Answer (score 1):

In the first example, with [256, (3,3), and the last thing], keras treats this list as having three dimensions or elements, when it is looking for four dimensions. Remove the parentheses to yield:

```
[256, 3, 3, input_shape=X.shape[1:]]
```